# What is the definition of knowledge within data science?

Tags: definitions, knowledge-base

"Knowledge" is crucial within several fields like Knowledge Discovery, Knowledge Distraction, Natural Language Processing, Data Mining, Big Data, etc etc etc.

**What is the definition of knowledge within these fields?**

**Is there 1 common definition, or does it depend on the exact context?**

Comment: prior? likelihood?

Comment: Is this not more of a discussion question than a question with an actual answer?

Comment: One cannot do science without a clear definition of terms, so I would be very surprised if there is no official, clear definition of this kind of knowledge

Answer (score 3):

The definition of *knowledge* varies based on the context, but can be broadly defined as **actionable** *information* based on further analysis (statistical, heuristic, or otherwise) of those patterns, associations, or relationships identified in the *raw data*.

Put another way, *knowledge* is defined by what *information* will most prove **actionable** based on the needs of the client or user (sometimes called the semantics).

Answer (score 3):

Knowledge is a *general* term and I don't think that there exist definitions of knowledge for specific disciplines, domains and areas of study. Therefore, in my opinion, knowledge, for a particular subject domain, can be defined just as a *domain-specific* (or *context-specific*, as mentioned by @JGreenwell +1) **perspective** (projection) of a general concept of knowledge.